# SQL Server : Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I have found many articles on dynamic pivots, selecting the data first and then running a 2nd query to do the pivot, however I have a large query that I require a dynamic pivot and am not sure how to get it working. The servers on each host can change this is why I need it to be dynamic. There is probably a very simple fix but I'm not great with SQL Server.

This is the code I have so far:

```
DECLARE @StartTime Date
DECLARE @EndTime Date

SET @StartTime = '2014-08-19 23:00:00'
SET @EndTime = '2014-08-22 09:21:33.557'

SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        [T1].[AvgMemoryUsage] AS C2, 
        CONVERT(varchar, [T1].[DateTime], 105) AS C3, 
        [T2].[Name] AS C4
     FROM 
        dbo.VIM_VMStatistics AS T1
     INNER JOIN 
        dbo.VIM_VirtualMachineNodes AS T2 ON [T1].[VirtualMachineID] = [T2].[VirtualMachineID]
     INNER JOIN 
        dbo.VIM_HostNodes AS T3 ON [T2].[HostID] = [T3].[HostID]
     LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.Nodes AS T8 ON [T3].[NodeID] = [T8].[NodeID]
     WHERE 
        [T8].[caption] = 'VMWARE-ESX01.Server.Local' 
        AND [T2].[PowerState] = 'poweredOn' 
        AND ([T2].[NodeID] IS NULL) 
        AND [T1].[DateTime] >= @StartTime 
        AND [T1].[DateTime] <= @EndTime

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT 
        [T4].[AvgMemoryUsage] AS C6, 
        CONVERT(varchar, [T4].[DateTime], 105) AS C7, 
        [T5].[Name] AS C8
     FROM 
        dbo.VIM_VMStatistics AS T4
     INNER JOIN 
        dbo.VIM_VirtualMachineNodes AS T5 ON [T4].[VirtualMachineID] = [T5].[VirtualMachineID]
     INNER JOIN 
        dbo.VIM_HostNodes AS T6 ON [T5].[HostID] = [T6].[HostID]
     LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.Nodes AS T7 ON [T5].[NodeID] = [T7].[NodeID]
     WHERE 
        [T6].[NodeID] = 1492 
        AND [T5].[PowerState] = 'poweredOn' 
        AND ([T5].[NodeID] IS NOT NULL) 
        AND [T4].[DateTime] >= @StartTime AND [T4].[DateTime] <= @EndTime)
) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT(
    AVG([c2])
    FOR [C4] IN ([server1],[server2],[server3],[server8],[server12])
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a dynamic pivot is fairly simple when you already know how pivot works. First you need to have a string with delimited columns to be pivoted. To achieve that you can use recommended `FOR XML PATH` and `QUOTENAME()`:

```
DECLARE @strPivotColumns nvarchar(max)
SELECT @strPivotColumns = STUFF((SELECT ','  +QUOTENAME([Name]) 
                   FROM dbo.VIM_VirtualMachineNodes FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Then you need to save the original query as a string and concatenate the string with column names:

```
DECLARE @StartTime Date
DECLARE @EndTime Date

SET @StartTime = '2014-08-19 23:00:00'
SET @EndTime = '2014-08-22 09:21:33.557'

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery nvarchar(2000)
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
'SELECT * FROM (
SELECT [T1].[AvgMemoryUsage] AS C2, CONVERT(varchar, [T1].[DateTime],105) AS C3, [T2].[Name] AS C4
FROM dbo.VIM_VMStatistics AS T1
INNER JOIN dbo.VIM_VirtualMachineNodes AS T2 ON [T1].[VirtualMachineID] = [T2].[VirtualMachineID]
INNER JOIN dbo.VIM_HostNodes AS T3 ON [T2].[HostID] = [T3].[HostID]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Nodes AS T8 ON [T3].[NodeID] = [T8].[NodeID]
WHERE [T8].[caption] = ''VMWARE-ESX01.Server.Local'' AND [T2].[PowerState] = ''poweredOn'' AND ([T2].[NodeID] IS NULL) AND [T1].[DateTime] >= @StartTime AND [T1].[DateTime] <= @EndTime
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT [T4].[AvgMemoryUsage] AS C6, CONVERT(varchar, [T4].[DateTime],105) AS C7, [T5].[Name] AS C8
        FROM dbo.VIM_VMStatistics AS T4
        INNER JOIN dbo.VIM_VirtualMachineNodes AS T5 ON [T4].[VirtualMachineID] = [T5].[VirtualMachineID]
        INNER JOIN dbo.VIM_HostNodes AS T6 ON [T5].[HostID] = [T6].[HostID]
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Nodes AS T7 ON [T5].[NodeID] = [T7].[NodeID]
        WHERE [T6].[NodeID] = 1492 AND [T5].[PowerState] = ''poweredOn'' AND ([T5].[NodeID] IS NOT NULL) AND [T4].[DateTime] >= @StartTime AND [T4].[DateTime] <= @EndTime
    )
)AS SourceTable 
PIVOT(
    AVG([c2])
    FOR [C4] IN (' + @strPivotColumns + ')
) AS PivotTable'
```

Then you can execute your query string:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery, N'@StartTime date, @EndTime date', @StartTime = @StartTime, @EndTime = @EndTime
```

EDIT BY STEVE: The following is the only thing now causing an issue with quotations:

```
FOR [C4] IN (' + @strPivotColumns + ')
```

ERROR: 
    Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
    Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'mad-a'.
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
    Incorrect syntax near 'mad-a'.

Comment: Hi Dimt, I have tried the above but just get errors: 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'VMWARE'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 28
Must declare the scalar variable "@StartTime".

Comment: @Steven ahh, sorry I have omitted the variable declaration. You still have to declare `DECLARE @StartTime Date DECLARE @EndTime Date
SET @StartTime = '2014-08-19 23:00:00' SET @EndTime = '2014-08-22 09:21:33.557'` as in your original query. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Steven I have also changed the EXEC statement because I've missed to include datatypes for parameters.

Comment: it doesn't seem to like the 'VMWARE-ESX01.Server.local' it looks like an escape issue, I have tried " and '' but neither seem to work any suggestions?

Comment: @Steven You need to double your speachmarks, I will edit the answer

Comment: sorry, that is what I already tried, it then gives the error:   
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'NodeID'.   
I know my syntax is correct though as ive tested it prior to this change.

Comment: @Steven ahh , increase the size of `DynamicPivotQuery nvarchar(1000)` to `DynamicPivotQuery nvarchar(2000)` :) that was my fault. It is hard to test such query without the actual scheme.

Comment: seems like it is nearly there now just trying to resolve one issue now which is happening from the STUFF(SELECT ',' +QUOTENAME([name])  
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'server01'.

Comment: @Steven Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59815/discussion-between-dimt-and-steven-marks).

Comment: So far we have found the outstanding issue to be `FOR [C4] IN (' + @strPivotColumns + ')` if I enter the string manually here it works fine, using the @strPivotColumns then causes a failure due to quotation end anyone able to assist please do!

Comment: @Steve increase DynamicPivotQuery nvarchar(2000) to DynamicPivotQuery nvarchar(max) and try again. Not sure if this will solve the problem but this variable should be set to max from the beginning as the concatenated variable is max.

Comment: you are a genius thanks so much for your help that has worked

Comment: @Steve glad could help, anyway I am far from genius by doing such mistakes with the variable size :)